# Inject a list of roles from application properties into a @PreAuthorize

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, authorization

Is there any trick for SPEL so I can define my admin roles in the application.yml and then load them directly into something like:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole(${my.security.admin-roles-list})")
```

...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Spring EL to access bean from @PreAuthorize annotation:

```
application.properties
  
my.security.admin-roles-list=RoleA,RoleB,RoleC

@Component("securityConfiguration")
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("#{'${my.security.admin-roles-list}'.split(',')}") 
    private List<String> adminRoles;

    public List<String> getAdminRoles() {
        return adminRoles;
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole(@securityConfiguration.getAdminRoles())")
```

Comment: Do you have the documentation for this by chance?

Comment: @Pat it's SpEl (Spring expression language), you can learn more about it in Spring doc